# How to search to the default index using NEST?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

This is my default index:

```
new ConnectionSettings(node).DefaultIndex("profiles")
```

I currently have this query where I need to perform the search using NEST:

```
GET profiles/_search
```

My problem is, NEST is requiring an object for Search method.

```
ElasticSearch.Search< object>()
```

How can I perform the search on profiles index itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `T` in NEST methods like `Search<T>()` is used for a couple of purposes:

1. Provide strongly typed access through lambda expressions for properties of `T`
2. In the case where an API returns a JSON document such as `Search<T>()` returning the originally indexed document under the `_source` field of each hit, `T` will be the type to which that document is deserialized.

If you don't need or desire either of those behaviours, you can use `object` or `dynamic` for `T` and specify strings for values such as `Field`. You'll then need to work out how to read that POCO; in the case of `dynamic`, the type returned is an internal `JObject` like type, so you could access properties on it dynamically.

In order to perform a search *without* a type in the URI, you can use

```
var searchResponse = client.Search<object>(s => s
    .AllTypes()
    .Query(q => q
        .Match(m => m
            .Field("some_field")
            .Query("match query")
        )
    )
);
```

which would yield a search request like

```
POST http://localhost:9200/profiles/_search 
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "some_field": {
        "query": "match query"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm! .AllTypes() is what I'm missing. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**ElasticSearch.Search()** doesn't search on the object. It uses your **profiles** index when you call Search method.

You will get a result after a search. The object is needed for it. 
Create a model class for profile with properties like below.

```
public class Profile
{
    public string Name{get;set;}
}
```

And call your ElasticSearch server with

```
ElasticSearch.Search<Profile>()
```

It will give you a profile list in result.